# Can I use Keymando To Bind Things With MonoDevelop?

Tags: keymando

I'm working with the lovely Keymando and also with MonoDevelop, but I couldn't figure out how to use the bindings.

Comment: do you have an actual question, rob? :D

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use Keymando with MonoDevelop. What are you trying to do?